# jacoco:check failing due to invalid parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jacoco, eclemma

I am trying to run a maven build in my eclipse environment and I receive the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.1.201212231917:check (check) on
>   project schedule-adapter: The parameters 'check' for goal
>   org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.1.201212231917:check are missing or
>   invalid -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.1.201212231917:check
>   (check) on project schedule-adapter: The parameters 'check' for goal
>   org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.1.201212231917:check are missing or
>   invalid   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)

I don't understand as this works in my other project in a different workspace. I copied the exact jacoco config over to my new project pom, and it reads as follows:

```
 <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
 <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>prepare-agent</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>report</id>
              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>check</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                <rules>
                  <rule>
                    <limits>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                      </limit>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>CLASS</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                      </limit>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>METHOD</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                      </limit>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                      </limit>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                      </limit>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                      </limit>
                    </limits>
                  </rule>
                </rules>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

My maven command from running in eclipse is

```
mvn clean install -e
```

Anything stand out to anyone? I've been trying to figure this out for a while. When I remove all of this from my pom, my project builds but jacoco is not checked.

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 3):

found the problem. the "rules" parameter is used for jacoco 0.6.3 and above. As you can see in my error, 0.6.1 was being pulled in. so i added the following dependency

Comment: following dependency... ?

Comment: unfortunately its been so long i don't even know where in my code i used it! But basically make sure the jacoco version is 0.6.3 and above :)